# Desktop effects could not be enabled on an Asus UL50vg

Tags: 10.10, drivers, nvidia, effects

I've got a problem with my graphic card. When I try to enable desktop effects on Ubuntu 10.10, "Desktop effects could not be enabled" message appears.

I have Asus ul50vg (nvidia G210M).
I don't use any xorg.conf file because when I generate it through nvidia-xconfig, only terminal appears after boot.

Do you have any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: Have you tried installing the official nVidia from their website?

Comment: It causes the same problem. After installation of the driver from nvidia website, Ubuntu drops to terminal during booting. When I remove xorg.conf, it boots normally. Desktop effects, however, can not be enabled anyway. So, the situation is the same as with the Ubuntu nvidia driver.

Comment: When I try to run compiz from terminal, I get: 

`Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
compiz (core) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to manage screen: 0
compiz (core) - Fatal: No manageable screens found on display :0.0
`

Comment: type this

    /usr/bin/jockey-gtk

in a terminal and see what it says.

Comment: It does not show any error. It says that the current nVidia driver is activated and currently in use.

Comment: Maybe, I have the problem because there are two graphic cards in my notebook. One integrated from Intel and one from nVidia. Although the drivers seem to be installed correctly, Ubuntu uses the integrated one.

Comment: Moreover, Ubuntu is unable to boot properly if the xorg.conf file generated automatically is in the system. It simply drops to terminal istead of showing graphical login prompt. When I remove the file, it boots normally, but without the nVidia card.

Comment: I noticed that there is no specification of bus id in xorg.conf. On the other hand, there is 'Load "glx"'. So, maybe the problem with compiz (missing glx) is caused by missing xorg.conf file. Therefore, the problem could be, maybe, stated otherwise: Why does not Ubuntu show graphical login prompt when using following xorg.conf?  
`Section "Screen"  
 Identifier "Default Screen"  
 DefaultDepth 24  
EndSection
  
Section "Module"  
 Load "glx"  
EndSection  
  
Section "Device"  
 Identifier "Default Device"  
 Driver "nvidia"  
 Option "NoLogo" "True"  
EndSection`

Comment: It seems to work now. I've changed IDE configuration in bios from Enhanced to Compatible. It's kind of weird because everything used to work with the Enhanced option. However, I think the problem is solved now. I would like to thank Shubh and Stephan for their answers.

Comment: @MichalPavelka Can you pleas answer your own question with what you did to correct this? It's best do to so for future people needing assistance

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed by the user by changing IDE mode from *Enhanced* to *Compatible* in the system BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install bumblebee to have both the Intel and Nvidia cards working simultaneously:
https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

```
sudo apt-get install git
# type password
git clone http://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee.git
cd bumblebee/
sudo ./install.sh
optirun glxgears
# check the speed and compare to running:
glxgears
# If you have google-chrome installed, you can try it with/without optirun and report the FPS values on the mailing list:
optirun google-chrome http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html
```